# How to remove ripple effect translucent overlay from custom shape

Tags: android, xml, material-design, ripple

I'm trying to add ripple effect to custom TextView in LinearLayout but the problem is that the main color of TextView is to be white but after applying ripple, the color of the TextView changes. I want that at first the background color of the TextView remains white and the ripple color must appear when touched.
Here is my code:

**ripple.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#A9A9A9">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
     <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
     <corners
       android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
       android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
       android:topRightRadius="0dp"
       android:topLeftRadius="30dp"/>
   </shape>
  </item>
</ripple>
```

**Main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="80"
    android:id="@+id/base_layout"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:clickable="true">
    <TextView
        android:text="What would you like to view?"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:id="@+id/selector_ask"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="News &amp; Events"
        android:textColor="@color/material_grey_800"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:id="@+id/selectorNews"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />
```

I tried using android:id="@android:id/mask" but no success. How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is one way of making a ripple effect, but try this simple method:

```
 android:foreground="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

add this to the view you want the ripple effect on and remove your old ripple.

Comment: This is not working for me. I set background to custom and foreground as you told, but no success